# Detect last non-zero value in rolling window

Tags: r, xts

I have a series as below -

```
set.seed(107)

test <- as.xts(rep(0,1000),Sys.Date()-1:1000)
test[sample(1000,50)] <- abs(100 * (1+rnorm(50)))
```

What I want to do, is output the latest non-zero value in this series on a rolling basis.

For example, let the rolling period be 20 days. So for each date, I want the output as the last non-zero value in the past 20 days before it.

Tried finding a runxxx function from TTR package for this, but nothing came up.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply` and custom function, you could also look at `rollapply` for similar functionality

```
#input
set.seed(107)

test <- as.xts(rep(0,1000),Sys.Date()-1:1000)
test[sample(1000,50)] <- abs(100 * (1+rnorm(50)))

#rolling calculations
lookbackPeriod = 20

rollNonZeroTS =
    do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(test),function(x) { 
    #for rows < lookbackPeriod, return NA
    if(x < lookbackPeriod) {
    windowTS=xts(NA,as.Date(index(test[x]))) 
    return(windowTS)
    }else{
    #for each date create a rolling window of length equal to lookbackPeriod, here = 20
    windowTS=test[(x-lookbackPeriod):x];
    # subset for non zero values and choose last value
    windowTS=tail(windowTS[windowTS!=0],1); 
    #if all values are zero in rolling window, output NA else last value
    windowTS=xts(ifelse(length(windowTS)==0,NA,windowTS),as.Date(index(test[x])))
    return(windowTS)    
    }                                         
    } ))
```

**Output**

```
head(test,30)
                 # [,1]
# 2013-12-20 101.651499
# 2013-12-21   0.000000
# 2013-12-22   0.000000
# 2013-12-23   0.000000
# 2013-12-24   0.000000
# 2013-12-25   0.000000
# 2013-12-26   0.000000
# 2013-12-27   0.000000
# 2013-12-28   0.000000
# 2013-12-29 101.108912
# 2013-12-30   0.000000
# 2013-12-31   0.000000
# 2014-01-01   0.000000
# 2014-01-02   0.000000
# 2014-01-03   0.000000
# 2014-01-04   0.000000
# 2014-01-05   0.000000
# 2014-01-06   0.000000
# 2014-01-07   0.000000
# 2014-01-08   0.000000
# 2014-01-09   0.000000
# 2014-01-10   0.000000
# 2014-01-11   0.000000
# 2014-01-12   2.025981
# 2014-01-13   0.000000
# 2014-01-14   0.000000
# 2014-01-15   0.000000
# 2014-01-16   0.000000
# 2014-01-17  50.922346
# 2014-01-18   0.000000


head(rollNonZeroTS,30)
                # [,1]
# 2013-12-20         NA
# 2013-12-21         NA
# 2013-12-22         NA
# 2013-12-23         NA
# 2013-12-24         NA
# 2013-12-25         NA
# 2013-12-26         NA
# 2013-12-27         NA
# 2013-12-28         NA
# 2013-12-29         NA
# 2013-12-30         NA
# 2013-12-31         NA
# 2014-01-01         NA
# 2014-01-02         NA
# 2014-01-03         NA
# 2014-01-04         NA
# 2014-01-05         NA
# 2014-01-06         NA
# 2014-01-07         NA
# 2014-01-08 101.108912
# 2014-01-09 101.108912
# 2014-01-10 101.108912
# 2014-01-11 101.108912
# 2014-01-12   2.025981
# 2014-01-13   2.025981
# 2014-01-14   2.025981
# 2014-01-15   2.025981
# 2014-01-16   2.025981
# 2014-01-17  50.922346
# 2014-01-18  50.922346
```

Comment: Hi,. thanks for the reply. It works. But I wrote a function myself, i'll post that too here, which is a bit more concise.

Comment: Logic is same, glad you worked it out. Do look out for  `rollapply` for simple window operations in future

Comment: Yes, it is. And Shall do! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this small function that solved the issue :

```
runLevel <- function(x,lagperiod){

  temp <- stats::lag(x,0:lagperiod)
  out <- x
  out[] <- apply(temp,1,function(x) {
    len <- length(x[x!=0])
    if (len>0) {
      head(x[x!=0],1)
    } else {NA}
  })

  return(out)

}
```

Using the inputs :

```
set.seed(107)

test <- as.xts(rep(0,1000),Sys.Date()-1:1000)
test[sample(1000,50)] <- abs(100 * (1+rnorm(50)))

runLevel(test,20)
```